# Combine Several Functions Which Produce Similar Behaviors

Tags: javascript, jquery, dry

I've got a page which, on desktop devices, can only be navigated using either scroll buttons, or a navigation pane. [Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/6zH4n/)

Here is the basic HTML template:

```
<header class="listGenHeader">
    <nav class="top-mid">
        <ul>
            <!-- .viewport navigation menu -->
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <nav class="top-right">
        <ul>
            <!-- Main navigation menu -->
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <nav class="mobile-nav">
        <!-- Mobile navigation menu -->
    </nav>
</header>
<div class="sales-pitch viewport">
    <!-- First .viewport -->
</div>
<div class="chooseTemplate viewport">
    <!-- Second .viewport -->
</div>
<div class="companyLogo viewport">
    <!-- Third .viewport -->
</div>
```

Each time the window is scrolled, the `active` class is removed from both the current `.viewport` and the current `ul.top-mid a` and added to the new `.viewport` and its corresponding `ul.top-mid a` with the following three (quite similar) functions:

```
// Get an array of class names
var cls = $('.top-mid a').map(function(){
    return $(this).attr('class');
});

// Scrolling Down
$('.scrollDown').click(function(e){

    // Keep page from trying to load hyperlinks
    e.preventDefault();

    // if We're at the top of the page, 
    // hide 'get started' button
    if ($('.getStarted:visible')) {
        $('.getStarted').fadeOut();
    }

    // Figure out what the next .viewport element is in the DOM
    var nextView = $('.viewport.active').next('.viewport');

    // If the next is the final, we don't need the scroll-down button anymore
    if (nextView.is('.viewport:last')) {
        $(this).fadeOut();
        $('.listGenFooter').animate({'bottom': '0'}, 300);
    }

    // Trade the main nav pane for the form sections nav
    // if we're scrolling down from the first viewport
    if ($('.top-right').is(':visible')) {
        $('.top-right').fadeOut(function(){
            $('a.logo').css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0', 'left': '0'})
                .animate({'left': '-10%'}, 300, function(){
                    $('.top-mid').fadeIn();
                    $('.mobile-nav').fadeIn();
            });
        });
    }

    // Show the scroll-up button, since we CAN scroll up
    $('.scrollUp').fadeIn();

    // Animate window to next viewport and remove
    // 'active' class from current viewport
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: nextView.offset().top}, 500);
    $('.viewport.active').removeClass('active');
    nextView.addClass('active');

    // loop through class names and highight
    // active item on the form sections nav
    for (var i = 0; i < cls.length; i++) {
        if (nextView.hasClass(cls[i])) {
            $('.top-mid a.' + cls[i]).addClass('active');
            $('.top-mid a.active').next('.triangle').show();
            $('.top-mid a').not('.' + cls[i]).removeClass('active');
            $('.top-mid a').not('.' + cls[i]).next('.triangle').hide();
        }
    }
});

// Scrolling up
$('.scrollUp').click(function(e){

    // Keep page from trying to load hyperlinks
    e.preventDefault();

    // Get previous viewport
    var prevView = $('.viewport.active').prev('.viewport');

    // If previous is the FIRST viewport, hide scroll-up button,
    // show get-started button and trade form sections nav
    // for the main nav again
    if (prevView.is('.sales-pitch')) {
        $('.scrollUp').fadeOut();
        $('.getStarted').fadeIn();
        $('.top-mid').fadeOut(function(){
            $('.mobile-nav, a.logo').hide(function(){
                $('.top-right').fadeIn();
                $('a.logo').css({'position': 'relative', 'top': '', 'left': ''}).fadeIn();
            });
        });
    }

    // If we're scrolling UP from the last viewport on the page,
    // show the scroll-down button again
    if ($('.viewport.active').is('.viewport:last')) {
        $('.scrollDown').fadeIn();
        $('.listGenFooter').animate({'bottom': '-100px'}, 300);
    }

    // Animate window to previous viewport
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: prevView.offset().top}, 500);

    // Remove 'active' class from current viewport
    // and add it to the one we're scrolling to.
    $('.viewport.active').removeClass('active');
    prevView.addClass('active');

    // Also highlight/unhighlight corresponding list items
    // in the form sections nav
    for (var i = 0; i < cls.length; i++) {
        if (prevView.hasClass(cls[i])) {
            $('.top-mid a.' + cls[i]).addClass('active');
            $('.top-mid a').not('.' + cls[i]).removeClass('active');
            $('.top-mid a.active').next('.triangle').show();
            $('.top-mid a').not('.active').next('.triangle').hide();
        }
    }
});

// Navigating via the form sections nav pane
$('.top-mid a').click(function(e){

    // Keep page from trying to load hyperlinks
    e.preventDefault();

    var self = $(this);
    for (var i = 0; i < cls.length; i++) {
        if (self.hasClass(cls[i])) {

            // If next viewport is LAST viewport
            if (cls[i] === "companyLogo") {

                // Hide scroll-down button and show footer
                $('.scrollDown').fadeOut();
                $('.listGenFooter').animate({'bottom': '0'}, 300);

            // Else show scroll-down button and hide footer
            } else {
                $('.scrollDown').show();
                $('.listGenFooter').animate({'bottom': '-100px'}, 300);
            }

            // Default behavior: scroll to viewport and toggle 'active' class
            // for visible viewport
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('.' + cls[i] + '.viewport').offset().top}, 500);
            $('.top-mid a.' + cls[i]).addClass('active');
            $('.viewport.' + cls[i]).addClass('active');
            $('.viewport').not('.' + cls[i] + '.viewport').removeClass('active');
            $('.top-mid a').not('.' + cls[i]).removeClass('active');
        }
    }

    // Toggle highlight triangles
    $('.top-mid a.active').next('.triangle').show();
    $('.top-mid a:not(.active)').next('.triangle').hide();
});
```

It's obvious that these three functions are producing essentially the same result (adding/removing `active` class and highlighting corresponding menu items), but I haven't been able to find a way to streamline them (it looks rather convoluted to me, and I actually KNOW what I'm looking at). Any suggestions would be awesome.

Comment: That first `if` statement has a bug - the function call (to jQuery) will *always* return a jQuery object, so the test will *always* be `true`.

Comment: Are you talking about the `if ($('.getStarted:visible'))` block? That condition returns `null` after the element is faded out. Maybe I don't understand your comment.

Comment: No, it won't return `null` - calling jQuery with a selector string will always return a jQuery object. It might be an *empty* jQuery object, but it won't be null.

Comment: Right, it returns an empty jQuery object. I'm not quite sure what you mean by its being a bug, though. Should I phrase the statement differently? It certainly produces the desired effect as is.

Comment: A jQuery object is always `true` in an `if` test (well any object is).  Since it's not `null`, it's `true`. Perhaps you meant `if ($('.getStarted').is(':visible'))` like you did in other places.

Comment: Okay, I got you. In fact that condition is extraneous, it seems. I'll edit it out. Thanks!

Comment: If i want just to reduce code repeating I would to use  ternar operators like here http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/6zH4n/1/ (incomplete)

Comment: @eicto: Thanks for the suggestion! That does reduce the amount of code a bit, but it also seems to increase the complexity of the function and does not (at least to my non-ternary-operator-comfortable eyes) seem to contribute to readability. Do you think it's better to shore up the code with ternary operators in this instance, or would you prefer more code and less complexity?

Comment: The complexity here is not a problem, the code repeat is much more problem than complexity, because if you have complex code, you can comment it well, but if you have bug in 10 same functions you will fix it never. :)  Anyway, if I would to do this task from scratch I probably would to change the code architecture, or may be just used angular and not worry at all :)

Comment: so hint here - use state based logic, not dom based, keep the current article number, change it with controls and evrytime you change it - render current state (make menu item active, hide or show buttons, etc)

Comment: That sounds a bit beyond my current skillset. Sounds like what you're saying ultimately is "learn Angular". It's on my list. The above is a small part of what you would probably tend to label a "web application" more so than a website.

Comment: there is dirty demo of what i mean http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/6zH4n/3

Comment: That's awesome. The only syntax/behavior that's unfamiliar to me are these: `$('.scrollUp')[id ? 'fadeIn' : 'fadeOut']();`. I understand what it's doing, obviously, but not how.

Comment: that is ternar, selects object method, because there are two ways to access object properties/methods object.method and object['method'] in other words method it is property wich value is function.

Comment: So, the expressions `id` and `id === l` in your `object[method]` construction will evaluate to either `true` or `false` and that determines which of the two methods will fire? BTW, you should post that as an answer :)